# How to get chat hostory SessionID Data from API.AI/Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have integrated API.AI in my website as chat box. When I browse other pages of the website, the chat history vanishes as expected. How can I retain these history data? How can I keep track of the current sessionID chat history?

Comment: You need to store chat in your database and create your custom chatbox then your problem may be solve